# Make "background" Chrome extension to modify the current page's code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a Chrome app that modifies the text and code of the current page in some way, but I have no idea if this is possible. The basic idea is this:

```
if(pagename == somepage) {
    $("#someid").html("whatever");
    $("#somebutton").click(function() {
        $("#someotherid").html("whatever");
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't want to have to click a button or icon to make that happen: I want that code to be executed as soon as the page is loaded. I had a look around Google on how to make Chrome extensions, but all the results show me how to make an extension that has an icon in the top right corner which opens a popup when clicked. Is it possible to make a "background" extension, such as this one?

Comment: As I was about to say before the question was deleted, you shouldn't have to click a button for it to happen. Look for "Content Scripts" in http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html

Comment: Does that mean I don't need a background.html?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to do, but if you want is just to "enrich" the page just by replacing some elements here and there, this should be enough.

Comment: One small point: you use "app" and "extension" interchangeably in your question, but they're very different things. Extensions make normal browsing better; apps usually don't involve browsing at all. It's an important distinction because you might find yourself reading app documentation, and it won't apply at all to your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a content script:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

From the page:

> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web
>   pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can
>   read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to
>   them.

Comment: This is the updated version of the link: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/